# Find the coefﬁcient of $x^{17}$ in $(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+...)^3.$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

This is #5 from Section 6.2 of *Applied Combinatorics* by *Alan Tucker*:

> Find the coefﬁcient of $x^{17}$ in $(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+...)^3.$

The books answer: $C(11+3−1,11)−C(3,1)×C(5+3−1,5)$.

I'm not sure where the second term comes from? Here is my work:

$$\begin{array}{l}
(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+\ldots)^3\\
=x^6(1 + x + x^2 + \ldots)^3\\
=x^6\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^3}\\
=x^6\left(1 + C(1+3-1,1)x + C(2 +3-1,2)x^2+C(3+3-1,3)x^3+ \ldots \right)
\end{array}$$

So, the coefficient of $x^{17}$ is really going to be the coefficient of $x^{11}$. So our answer is: $$C(11+3-1,11).$$

But that's only half the book answer stated above. Why?

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072372/faster-way-to-find-coefficient-of-xn-in-1-x-x2-x3-xak?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer is right, your book is wrong.  Here are two alternative ways to prove it:

1. The coefficient of $x^{11}$ is the number of ways to put 11 $x$'s in 3 baskets.  This is the "[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))" problem, and the answer is $\binom{11+3-1}{3-1}$.
2. [Expand and look at the $x^{11}$ term.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%2Bx%5E7%2Bx%5E8%2Bx%5E9%2Bx%5E10%2Bx%5E11)%5E3)

Comment: Wow! Interesting. For future readers, this is #5 from Section 6.2 of Applied Combinatorics by Alan Tucker.

Comment: @user3724404 The mistake doesn't seem to be listed in the [errata](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~tucker/ApCombcorrect.html). Perhaps you should email the author to let him know!