# Coefficient of $x^k$ in polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

Let $k, n, m \in \mathbb{N}, k \le n.$ Find the formula for coefficient of $x^k$ in $(x^n + x^{(n-1)} + ... + x^2 + x + 1)^m$.

answer is in this question: [faster-way-to-find-coefficient-of-xn-in-1-x-x2-x3-xak](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072372/faster-way-to-find-coefficient-of-xn-in-1-x-x2-x3-xak)

But I still don't understand some parts of the answer.

So we can write the polynomial as:
$$
\left( \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} \right)^{m}
$$

$$
= (1-x^{n+1})^m \cdot (1-x)^{-m}
$$

All that I understand,
but now we write that as a sum:
$$
= \sum_{i=0}(-1)^i {m\choose i}x^{(n+1)i}\cdot\sum_{j=0} {j+m-1\choose j}x^j
$$

1. both of the sums go up to $n$?
2. What's the second sum?

And then finally we have the coefficient: $x^k$:
$$
\sum_{i=0}(-1)^i {m\choose i} {j+m-1\choose j} 
$$
Where do we get $j$? Is one sum missing here?

I'm quite lost in both of the formulas with sums. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Also the OP mentions

> I want to avoid iterating over N
> to find the sum of products of certain coefficients, in the usual solution to this problem.

What's that usual solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right that the summations are not properly indexed, so let's make the notations clear.

---

For $(1-x^{n+1})^m$, the power is a positive integer, so we can use the usual [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement) to get

$$(1-x^{n+1})^m=\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^i{m\choose i}x^{(n+1)i}.$$

For $(1-x)^{-m}$, the power is a negative integer, so we use the [negative binomial theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/negative-binomial-theorem/) to get

$$(1-x)^{-m}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty{m+j-1\choose j}x^j.$$

Note that the above sum is to $\infty$ and we need $|x|<1$. Now multiply these two sums, we have

$$\left(\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)^m=\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^i{m\choose i}{m+j-1\choose j}x^{(n+1)i+j}.$$

Therefore, the coefficient for $x^k$ is given by

$$\sum_{\substack{0\leq i\leq m,\ j\geq0\\(n+1)i+j=k}}(-1)^i{m\choose i}{m+j-1\choose j}.$$

---

As for the *usual solution* mentioned by the OP, I believe it is to directly expand $(1+x+\cdots+x^n)^m$ using the usual binomial theorem, and then find the coefficient of $x^k$, but this could be tedious since we need to iterate over $n$. In comparison, the OP's method is to use the sum formula of geometric progressions $1+\cdots+x^n=(1-x^{n+1})/(1-x)$, so that we only have the product of two simple sums without needing to iterate over $n$.

Comment: Thank you, it is very much clear now. However I've got one more question regarding the last summation. Is this the same? $\sum_{\substack{i=0, \\j = k - (n+1)*i}}^{m}$. Basically a summation from $i=0$ up to $m$, where $j$ is set. Or did I misunderstand that?

Comment: @popcorn You are welcome. For the last summation, we are summing over all pairs $(i,j)$ such that $0\leq i\leq m$, $j\geq0$ and $(n+1)i+j=k$. So you can think we are summing over the set $\{(i,j)\}$ where $i,j$ satisfy those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether I answer the OP question directly.

However under the condition $k \leq n$, I think there is a simple approach using stars and bars method.

Let us try to check the idea under a simple example first.

Question: Find the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3$.

Note that $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3$$
$$=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$$

The coefficient of $x^4$ is obtained by counting the number of terms of the form  $x^{r_1}x^{r_2}x^{r_3}$
where $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are non-negative integers such that $r_1+r_2+r_3=4$

This is equivalent to finding the number of solutions of $$r_1+r_2+r_3=4$$
where $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are non-negative integers.

By stars and bars method, the answer is $$\binom{4+3-1}{4}=15$$

Exactly the same reasonings apply to our question here.

Finding the coefficient of $x^k( k \leq n)$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+ \cdots +x^n)^m$ is the same as finding the number of solutions of
$$r_1+r_2+r_3+ \cdots + r_m=k$$
where $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots,  r_m$ are non-negative integers.

Hence the answer is $$\binom{k+m-1}{k}.$$

(Note that the formula is correct only when $k \leq n.$)

Comment: That's an interesting approach. What's the reasoning that it can only work when $k \le n$?

Comment: @popcorn Let's consider why the formula does not work in finding the coefficient of $x^6$ ($k \gt n$) in the expansion of $(1+x+ \cdots + x^4)^3$. The stars and bars method finds the number of $(r_1, r_2, r_3)$ such that $r_1+r_2+r_3=6$ and $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are non-negative integers. This includes cases like $(r_1, r_2, r_3)=(1, 0, 5)$ and $(0, 0, 6)$. But each $x^{r_i}$ comes from $1+x+ \cdots + x^4$ and hence $r_i \leq 4$. Therefore cases like $(r_1, r_2, r_3)=(1, 0, 5)$ and $(0, 0, 6)$ must be discounted.

This situation does not arise when we find the coefficient of $x^4$ $(k \leq n)$.

Answer (score 1):

In this approach, the denominator and numerator are processed in separate steps. It might help to better see what's going on. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^k]}&\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)^{m}}\\
> &=[x^k]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-m}{j}(-x)^j\left(1-x^{n+1}\right)^m\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{m+j-1}{j}[x^{k-j}]\left(1-x^{n+1}\right)^m\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{m+k-j-1}{k-j}[x^{j}]\sum_{l=0}^m\binom{m}{l}(-x)^{(n+1)l}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{n+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{m+k-(n+1)j-1}{k-(n+1)j}
> [x^{(n+1)j}]\sum_{l=0}^m\binom{m}{l}(-x)^{(n+1)l}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{n+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{m+k-(n+1)j-1}{k-(n+1)j}\binom{m}{j}(-1)^j}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we expand the denominator using a *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ and apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$. We also set the upper limit of the sum to $k$ since other summands do not contribute.
- In (3) we change the order of summation of the left sum $j\to k-j$ and expand the binomial. We see the power $j$ has to be an $(n+1)$-multiple of $l$.
- In (4) we take only $(n+1)$-multiples of $j$, since other summands do not contribute.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^{(n+1)j}$ by taking $l=j$.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that these numbers are called the Bi$^{s}$nomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}_{s}$, where
$$(1+x+x^{2}+\ldots+x^{s})^{n}=\sum\limits_{k\geq 0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}_{s}x^{k}. $$

See Table 1 in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-019-1457-0) for more notations and names of these numbers.